# Measure group membership

Tags: r

I have a data frame of student data that contains 31 variables.  for the purposes of this problem, I am only interested in the following columns.  I have arranged them like so for demonstration:

```
id  year    action
1   2009-10 A
2   2009-10 A
3   2009-10 A
1   2010-11 A
2   2010-11 declined
3   2010-11 declined
1   2011-12 A
```

I would like to produce a summary of student enrollment over three years.  creating a frequency table gets me very close to the results I want:

```
table(dem$id, dem$year)

   2009-10 2010-11 2011-12
  1       1       1       1
  2       1       1       0
  3       1       1       0
```

however, it doesn't take into account the "action"column (obviously).  I need to measure enrollment based on

1) did a student drop out?  if they do drop out after 2009-10, there will not be a record for them in this database

2) do they accept?  if the answer is anything other than "A", the student has not accepted

The my ideal output would look something like this:

```
    id  2009-10 2010-11 2011-12
  1       1       1       1
  2       1       0       0
  3       1       0       0
```

I've tried some combinations of ddply(summarize) and ifelse(), but my implementation must be odd because I don't get the results I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
table(dem[c("id", "year", "action")])
```

Produces:

```
, , action = A

   year
id  2009-10 2010-11 2011-12
  1       1       1       1
  2       1       0       0
  3       1       0       0

, , action = declined

   year
id  2009-10 2010-11 2011-12
  1       0       0       0
  2       0       1       0
  3       0       1       0
```

If you only want the `A`, you can subset `dem` as well (though `action` needs to be character for this to only show `A`):

```
table(subset(dem[c("id", "year", "action")], action=="A"))
```

Comment: This works well for my demonstration data, however, my actual dataset has around 30 columns, so this causes an error when I run it on the whole thing.  Completely forgot to put this in the question, will edit.

Comment: @Mike, just subset the columns first.  Assuming the first three are the meaningful ones for this: `table(dem[1:3])`, or alternatively `table(dem[c("id", "year", "action")])`

Comment: didn't know table had that kind of functionality (it's always the simple things).